# what does "andw $~3, %dx "means?

Tags: assembly

the piece of code comes from linux kernel source code. What exactly does the $~3 mean? I konw $3 means an  immediate number, but what is it with a leading  symbol ~  ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Bitwise complement. So anding with ~3 means clearing the two lowest bits.

Comment: 3 is 11 in binary; it has only two bits set. Those are the bits of `%dx` that are being cleared.

Comment: Does the symbol ~ mean NOT?